# How to use AudioSource in Unity3d's Timeline?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried to use timeline feature with Audio Track but when I dragged GameObject with audio source into Audio Track, it showed me as it assigned successfully but I cannot control anything like sound volume from that audio source. If I remove audio source from audio track in Timeline, sound still playable as well which is not right. What should I do to control AudioSource in Unity3d's Timeline?